# Camera shader to change the target render texture alpha value

Tags: glsl, unity-game-engine

Is there a pre-maid unity shader so that my camera will render different alpha values depending on the color of what it sees?

For example, If i had a Gray square with a black square inside, the camera would render into the texture the current texture color with a 50% alpha on where the gray square is, + the current texture color with a 100% alpha where the black one is?

If there isn't one already made at least i'd like to confirm this is the correct approach so that i can try making the shader myself.

Thanks

Comment: I've not understood your question: this gray square is meant to work like a filter for objects behind it? Or it's going to modify its own color?

Comment: Its meant to modify its render texture target, so for anything that has been already drawn, it will modify its alpha value of the currently drawn things.